# How do i put the total sum of prime numbers first, then the prime numbers below it

Tags: java, loops, numbers

I'm currently using this code, and I'm trying to output the total sum of how many prime numbers first and then the prime numbers list

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int r, s = 0;
        
        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        r = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println();
        
        for (int i = 2; i < r; i++) {
            
            int f = 0;
            
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                
                if (i%j == 0)
                    f = 1;
            }
            
            if (f == 0) {
                
                System.out.print(i+ " ");
                s = s +1;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println("N =" +s);
    }
    
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
Input number: 10

2 3 5 7 N = 4
```

But what I'm looking for is this result:

```
Input number: 10

N = 4
2 3 5 7
```

I don't know how, I tried putting the S.O.P in different places and I can't figure out how.

Comment: You probably want to add the primes you find to some kind of structure, such as an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and print them out in a loop at the end.

Comment: You are calculating `N` on the fly and then printing it. You need to calculate it beforehand and make a `print` statement before the `for` loop starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display `N = 4` before `2 3 5 7`, you can append the numbers (i.e. `2 3 5 7`) to a `StringBuilder` and print the same after printing `N = 4` e.g.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r, s = 0;
        StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        r = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 2; i < r; i++) {
            int f = 0;

            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {

                if (i % j == 0)
                    f = 1;
            }

            if (f == 0) {
                numbers.append(i).append(' ');// Append to StringBuilder instead of printing
                s = s + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("N =" + s);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Input number: 10

N =4
2 3 5 7
```

**Note:** for [checking the primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), checking up to `Math.sqrt(i)` is sufficient i.e. you should replace  `j < i` with `j <= Math.sqrt(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can store the numbers in a list and then print them after the loop is over** 
Don't worry if you have not studied lists yet cause you will have to soon anyways.

here's the code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int r, s = 0;
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    System.out.print("Input number: ");
    r = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 2; i < r; i++) {

        int f = 0;

        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {

            if (i%j == 0)
                f = 1;
        }

        if (f == 0) {

            //System.out.print(i+ " ");
            list.add(i);
            s = s +1;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("N = " +s);

    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
    }
}
```